# Finding a textbox inside InsertItemTemplate in Listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
Dim txt As TextBox = CType(lv2.Items(lv2.SelectedIndex) _
    .FindControl("txtCode"), TextBox)
```

What is the solution please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim txtCode As TextBox = _
      CType(lv2.InsertItem.FindControl("txtCode"), TextBox)
```